# Android Studio: emulator: warning: opening audio input failed creating window 61 83 462 820

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools, android-virtual-device

I am getting this error everytime I try to launch my AVD: `emulator: warning: opening audio input failed` `creating window 61 83 462 820`

Have tried, editing, deleting, and modifying my devices and also re-installed Android Studio. Also, started from scratch on the project I am working and so far no success. This error showed up ever since (not sure if its the motive) I tried to view my project through my nexus 5 hardware and decided to uninstall the driver I had (Clockwork Mod Universal ADB driver) to Google's adb driver that you download from SDK manager.

Any suggestion would be helpful...

**UPDATE**

Just tried it from my nexus 5 and it enters smoothly without the error but from the emulator it doesnt enter smoothly...